# Sudoers file permissions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to run the following command without the need for sudo:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee -a /sys/block/$hd/device/delete
```

The $hd variable changes dynamically from sdb -> sdi for each one of my HDD's in my drive bay.

I added the following line to the sudoers file:

```
operator ALL=/sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

But this didn't make a difference its still asking for sudo password even if I run:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee -a /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: Perhaps a Serverfault question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sudoers` line can only point to the command you're intended to run, not the destination output file. Anything under that `/sys` is a special device that characters are written to.

What you want to do is create a script that will do `echo 1 > /sys/block/$hd/device/delete` where $hd is checked to match the regular expression `/sd[b-i]/`. Point the sudo command at that script rather than where you have it.

Also, Michael Hampton is right: somebody **will** run a delete command you don't want mess things up. If you don't have  proper backups, then your data never existed.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a script (you ARE writing a script, right?) and grant the user `sudo` access to the script.

It'll probably end up looking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for kill_this_disk in /sys/block/sd[b-i]/device/delete
do
    echo 1 > $kill_this_disk
done
```

And, I hope you have good backups.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think **operator ALL=/sys/block/sdb/device/delete ** will enable you to access that device even as non root. The sudoers enables you to specify commands which will not query for the password when ran as sudo (here "tee" for example). Your problem comes from permissions on the /sys/block/$hd/device/delete...

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you need to use the NOPASSWD option in the sudoers configuration file.  I believe the syntax is something like this:

```
operator ALL=NOPASSWD:/sys/block/sdb/device/delete
```

Comment: -1. Sudo specifies the command to run. This is the system object file that is being written to.